# how to align 5 div side by side in center using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, center

I have  problem to make a div always center, when we going to tab also...

**What actually there:**

HTML

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: #09c;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ravinthranath/2q3q08f7/

**What I need actually:**!
[image]

Can you help me to solve this issues...?

Comment: If you have code...and you should, please provide it. It's a requirement.

Comment: please set up a fiddle with a minimal example and tell us the browser/css requirements (if any)

Comment: Sorry for the issue... This is my first question to post, so i can't how to explain... That is the problem sorry for the troubles @Paulie_D

Comment: @RaviDelixan That's why you should take the [**Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the guidelines on what types of questions can be asked.

Comment: Definitely will do that on next time, Thanks for the support @Paulie_D

Comment: Thanks for the mention. I will didn't do that once again @FabrizioCalderan..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the display mode of your divs to `inline-block` will allow you to center them in the parent element

```css
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrap > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #1ea0e9;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your squares in a container and add `text-align:center` to it.

This does not only align the text to the center - it also aligns the div elements as well.

Here's a quick demo of this in action:

```css
.wrap{
  text-align:center;
  }
.box{
  height:24vw;
  width:24vw;
  background:aqua;
  margin:1vw;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

In your specific case, the text align property would not work directly due to your use of the float property.

Changing your col class to `display:inline-block` instead of <strike>`float:left`</strike> would allow you to align them in this way:

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
.col {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: #09c;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ncev37f/2/)**

css:

```
 .center {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #09c;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height:140px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7kxxxcc/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>

.container{
  text-align: center;
}
.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #bada55;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```